# Toolbar bottom iOS 16 - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios15, ios16

I would like to have a bottom toolbar with SwiftUI.
The following is working in iOS 15, but not in iOS 16.
In iOS 16 the toolbar is not showing. (It's working if I change the placement...)

```swift
Text("Content")
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) {
            Button("Greeting") { 
                print("Hello world!")
            }
        }
    }
```

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75M4N.png)

Do you have any workaround for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`toolbar` depends on the navigation bar so you have to have a `NavigationView`/`NavigationStack`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/toolbar(content:)-5w0tj

```
struct ToolbarSolutionView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{ //NavigationStack
            Text("Content")
            
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) {
                        Button("Greeting") {
                            print("Hello world!")
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

It was likely a bug that it was working before.

You can hide the navigation bar if you don't need it.

```
//iOS 13+
.navigationBarHidden(true)

//iOS 16+
.toolbar(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)
```

Comment: The annoying aspect to the NavigationView requirement is that the color-setting on it is broken. NavigationView ignores background and foreground color settings.

Answer (score 3):

For me, any conditional `bottomBar` does not get displayed at all, even if `showTB == true` on iOS 16.

```
  .toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
      if showTB {
        Button("Delete") {
          print(234)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Testing on the iOS 16.1 Beta, it seems to be fixed for iOS 16.1 though.

Comment: Probably I have similar issue, however I use 2 toolbar items – `.bottomBar` and `.keyboard`. When I use conditional in `.bottomBar`, `.keyboard` toolbar doesn't display at all. And I found what is causing this issue: it's working as expected using `NavigationView` but not with `NavigationStack`. Haven't tested it on iOS 16.1 yet.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue. It is resolved after updating to iOS 16.1.